# Laptop for coding (XPS 15 vs ZenBook Pro)

Tags: laptop, development

I am currently looking for a laptop to use for university next year. I will be studying Computer Sciences and I am still debating which laptop I should get.

These where the laptops I had in mind:

- **Dell XPS 15 9570** (€ 1.829,00)

  - i7-8750H processor (4,1 GHz; 6-cores)
  - 16 GB DDR4, 2.666 MHz
  - 512 GB M.2 2280 PCIe
  - NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050Ti 4 GB GDDR5
  - 1920 x 1080 15'' display.
  - Up to 11h of battery life (97-Wh)
- **Asus ZenBook Pro UX550VD** (€1.599)

  - i7-7700HQ processor (3,8 GHz; 4-cores)
  - 16 GB SO-DIMM DDR4
  - 512 GB M.2 PCIe
  - NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 4 GB GDDR5
  - 1920 x 1080 15'' display.
  - Up to 8h of battery life

The XPS has better battery life and has a better screen.

The ZenBook is cheaper, has more ports but has an older processor and CPU.

Maby their is another laptop that is better. I would love to see different suggestions. Please note that since I am living in Belgium not every laptop is available here.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Why are you focusing on the XPS 15 and ZenBook Pro specifically? Not that they're bad laptops, but I'm trying to understand what you want. What's your budget like? Do you game? Do you care about resolution/color/refresh rate? Weight? Battery life?